# Problema con utf8 en código de Odoo local y conexión a PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

he instalado Odoo en local y estoy creando algunos modulos propios,el caso es que ya tengo creado el modulo e instalado,y al reiniciar el servidor para que se me cree la tabla en la base de datos me aparece lo siguiente en el cmd:

```
AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte
```

he probado a cambiar la codificacion a Latin-1,ero sigue igual